# Filtering based on a date within a matching object in an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, filter, aggregate

We have a collection of documents that look like this:
[image]

The timeline holds different events that happened with a particular object. I am trying to find a way to filter objects based on the date within the `timeline` object with `status` `CREATED`.

If I understand that correctly, I have to do it through aggregations. One possible article in the direction is this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/

The way I am thinking about it is to add this matching timeline item as an additional field and match on that.

Is there an easier (faster) way to achieve it?

The result I am looking for is a collection of documents within a certain month based on the `date` field in the `CREATED` item under a `timeline`.
So, every document has an object under `timeline` with a status `CREATED`. That object has a `date` field. I need to filter the collection by that.
Then run a bunch of aggregates on the filtered collection.

**EDIT** - Adding more data

**Full Document**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55762fbf86c273233aebc101"
    },
    "from": {
        "nickname": "Savings",
        "type": "TYPE-US",
        "id": "5574edcc86c27322ef865ea4",
        "user": {
            "legal_names": [
                "Some new name"
            ],
            "_id": "557387ed86c27318532fc09a"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "ip": "192.168.0.1",
        "supp_id": "1283764wqwsdd34wd13212",
        "webhook": "http://requestb.in/1acojwy1",
        "process_on": {
            "$date": "2015-06-10T00:13:51.263Z"
        },
        "note": "Deposit",
        "created_on": {
            "$date": "2015-06-09T00:13:51.263Z"
        },
        "other": {
            "skip_validation": false,
            "do_next": true
        },
        "latlon": "0,0",
        "same_day": false
    },
    "timeline": [
        {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2015-06-09T00:13:51.263Z"
            },
            "status": "CREATED",
            "note": "Transaction created",
            "status_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "status": "CANCELED",
            "note": "",
            "datetime": {
                "$date": "2015-06-25T00:37:00.515Z"
            },
            "status_id": "-1"
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2015-07-07T07:16:44.756Z"
            },
            "status": "CREATED",
            "note": "Transaction unqueued",
            "status_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2015-07-07T07:16:44.809Z"
            },
            "status": "PROCESSING-DEBIT",
            "note": "Transaction debit being processed.",
            "status_id": "2"
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2015-07-07T07:16:44.853Z"
            },
            "status": "PROCESSING-CREDIT",
            "note": "Transaction credit being processed.",
            "status_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2015-07-07T07:16:47.051Z"
            },
            "status": "SETTLED",
            "note": "Transaction credit has been made.",
            "status_id": "4"
        }
    ],
    "to": {
        "nickname": "ACH-US",
        "type": "ACH-US",
        "id": "5574d23b86c27354b2db471e",
        "user": {
            "legal_names": [
                "Some new name"
            ],
            "_id": "557387ed86c27318532fc09a"
        }
    },
    "amount": {
        "currency": "cUSD",
        "amount": 1010
    },
    "client": {
        "id": 844,
        "name": "Bob Joe"
    },
    "fees": [
        {
            "note": "Company Facilitator Fee",
            "to": {
                "id": "559339aa86c273605ccd35df"
            },
            "fee": 25
        },
        {
            "note": "Facilitator Fee",
            "to": {
                "id": "559339aa86c273605ccd35df"
            },
            "fee": 100
        }
    ],
    "recent_status": {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-07-07T07:16:47.051Z"
        },
        "status": "SETTLED",
        "note": "Transaction credit has been made.",
        "status_id": "4"
    },
    "_v": 2
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to return the entire matching document? or return matching documents with non-matching timeline entries removed?

Comment: @Joe I will need to run aggregates and stats on some data on these objects. So, I will need the objects.

Comment: can you give the data in JSON, and the expected output? also any variable you want to use for exampple you have a date that you want to compare with the dates on timeline?

Comment: @Takis_ Added more details

Comment: Your example shows two entries for CREATED - one on 2015-06-09T00:13:51.263Z and another on 2015-07-07T07:16:44.756Z.  A query trying to find documents with a timeline of 'CREATED' in the month of July will find this document, as will a query for the month of June.  Is this expected?

Comment: @barrypicker This is an exceptional case, but yes, normal. The most important is the original creation (first one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on my understanding, you can have more than one `CREATED` in the timeline, but if that entry exists for the month you are inquiring about the document is valid for retrieval.  Here is an aggregation which uses `$elemMatch` to find these documents...

```
Enterprise atlas-7aocnr-shard-0 [primary]> db.collection.find( { timeline: { $elemMatch: { status: "CREATED", $and: [ { date: { $gte: ISODate("2015-06-01") } }, { date: { $lt: ISODate("2015-07-01") } } ] } } } )
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("55762fbf86c273233aebc101"),
    from: {
      nickname: 'Savings',
      type: 'SYNAPSE-US',
      id: '5574edcc86c27322ef865ea4',
      user: {
        legal_names: [ 'Some new name' ],
        _id: '557387ed86c27318532fc09a'
      }
    },
    extra: {
      ip: '192.168.0.1',
      supp_id: '1283764wqwsdd34wd13212',
      webhook: 'http://requestb.in/1acojwy1',
      process_on: 2015-06-10T00:13:51.263Z,
      note: 'Deposit to bank account',
      created_on: 2015-06-09T00:13:51.263Z,
      other: { skip_validation: false, do_next: true },
      latlon: '0,0',
      same_day: false
    },
    timeline: [
      {
        date: 2015-06-09T00:13:51.263Z,
        status: 'CREATED',
        note: 'Transaction created',
        status_id: '1'
      },
      {
        status: 'CANCELED',
        note: '',
        datetime: 2015-06-25T00:37:00.515Z,
        status_id: '-1'
      },
      {
        date: 2015-07-07T07:16:44.756Z,
        status: 'CREATED',
        note: 'Transaction unqueued',
        status_id: '1'
      },
      {
        date: 2015-07-07T07:16:44.809Z,
        status: 'PROCESSING-DEBIT',
        note: 'Transaction debit being processed.',
        status_id: '2'
      },
      {
        date: 2015-07-07T07:16:44.853Z,
        status: 'PROCESSING-CREDIT',
        note: 'Transaction credit being processed.',
        status_id: '3'
      },
      {
        date: 2015-07-07T07:16:47.051Z,
        status: 'SETTLED',
        note: 'Transaction credit has been made.',
        status_id: '4'
      }
    ],
    to: {
      nickname: 'ACH-US',
      type: 'ACH-US',
      id: '5574d23b86c27354b2db471e',
      user: {
        legal_names: [ 'Some new name' ],
        _id: '557387ed86c27318532fc09a'
      }
    },
    amount: { currency: 'cUSD', amount: 1010 },
    client: { id: 844, name: 'Sankaet Pathak' },
    fees: [
      {
        note: 'Synapse Facilitator Fee',
        to: { id: '559339aa86c273605ccd35df' },
        fee: 25
      },
      {
        note: 'Facilitator Fee',
        to: { id: '559339aa86c273605ccd35df' },
        fee: 100
      }
    ],
    recent_status: {
      date: 2015-07-07T07:16:47.051Z,
      status: 'SETTLED',
      note: 'Transaction credit has been made.',
      status_id: '4'
    },
    _v: 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter only the "CREATED" objects inside the  timeline array , this is the way to go:

```
mongos> db.z.aggregate([  
{ 
 $project:{ 
           timelines:{ 
                 $filter:{ 
                   input:"$timeline" , 
                      as:"item" , 
                    cond: { $eq:["$$item.status","CREATED" ]  }
                         }
                    } 
           } 
 }    ]).pretty()

{
"_id" : {
    "oid" : "55762fbf86c273233aebc101"
},
"timelines" : [
    {
        "date" : {
            "$date" : "2015-06-09T00:13:51.263Z"
        },
        "status" : "CREATED",
        "note" : "Transaction created",
        "status_id" : "1"
    },
    {
        "date" : {
            "$date" : "2015-07-07T07:16:44.756Z"
        },
        "status" : "CREATED",
        "note" : "Transaction unqueued",
        "status_id" : "1"
    }
]
}
 mongos>
```

Comment: This does not filter for the documents having a created during a specific month.

Answer (score 0):

you can use: $unwind to extract data from arrays as individual document. check here [mongodb unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).